# Laravel livewire checkbox options not being checked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I tried many ways of populating old checked values in edit page of livewire.

Method 1 :

```
public $role_id, $name, $new_permissions = [];
public function mount($id)
{
/

$old_permissions = \App\Models\UserRolePermission::where('user_role_id', $this->role_id)->pluck('permission_id')->toArray();
// here new_permissions is my wire:model name in view for the checkbox input
// so I tried to initialize the new_permissions array by old_permissions array
    $this->new_permissions = $old_permissions;
    $this->role_id = $id;
}
```

Method 2 :

Manually fetched the permissions in the view and checked in_array for the old_permissions to be checked:

```
@php
    $old_permissions = \App\Models\UserRolePermission::where('user_role_id', $this->role_id)->pluck('permission_id')->toArray();
@endphp
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="display-block text-semibold">Select Permissions</label>
                    @foreach($permissions as $item)
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" wire:model="new_permissions" class="" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ in_array($item->id, $old_permissions) ? "checked" : "" }}>
                            {{ $item->name }} </label>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the 2nd method, my code in view source was correct, the old ones had checked in input field and the new ones didnt, but in the view the checkboxes didn't appear to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Livewire use string value instead of numeric.

To fix it convert all integers in your $old_permissions array to strings like

```
$old_permissions = \App\Models\UserRolePermission::where('user_role_id', $this->role_id)->pluck('permission_id')->->map(function ($permission_id) {
      return  strval($permission_id);
})->toArray();
```

Here is my solution

**In View**

```
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-primary-900 rounded-md shadow mt-2 py-3 px-2">
    <h3 class="mb-2 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 text-xl">Permissions</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
        @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4 md:col-span-3 flex items-center space-x-2">
                <input wire:model="selectedPermissions" type="checkbox" value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                    class="w-4 h-4 transition text-primary duration-300 rounded focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-0 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-200 dark:focus:ring-primary-700">
                <label class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-100">
                    {{ ucwords($permission->display_name) }}
                </label>

            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

**In Livewire Component Class**

```
public $role;
public $permissions;
public $selectedPermissions = [];

protected $listeners = ['eidtRole'];

public function mount()
{
    $this->permissions = Permission::get();
}
public function eidtRole(Role $role)
{
    $this->role = $role;
    $this->selectedPermissions = $this->rolePermissions = $role->permissions()->pluck('id')->map(function ($id) {
    return strval($id);
    })->toArray();
}
```